# Why can't I return value using obj in class when i use recursion?

Tags: php, function, class, recursion

Writing a factorial program using recursion ,class and function.

Shows error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function fact()

```
 class factorial{
       public function fact($n){
              if($n==1){
                 return 1;
               }

               else{
                   return $n*fact($n-1);                       
               }
       }
   }

$obj= new factorial();
$print=$obj->fact(3);
echo $print;
```

Comment: `return $n*fact($n-1); ` but fact is a class member... try `$this->fact(...)`

Comment: i tired return $this->n=$n *fact($this->n=$n-1);                       but it dosnt works

Comment: @DhruvThakkar Not to sound mean, but you don't seem to understand what you're doing. Take a look at [Classes and Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) from the manual.

Comment: The `$this->` has to be on the method `fact()` otherwise it doesn't know where to look for the function.  You shouldn't have it on `$n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in line number 11 ie;

```
return $n*fact($n-1);
```

the method fact was not called properly in this. You have to use $this operator to call the function within that class on any method.

So, you just have to change that to `$this->fact($n-1)`

For convenience I am providing the whole revised code here below, have a look into it.

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

class factorial{
       public function fact($n){
              if($n==1){
                 return 1;
               }

               else{
                   return $n*$this->fact($n-1);                       
               }
       }
   }

$obj= new factorial();
$print=$obj->fact(3);
echo $print;
```

You can check the code working here in the link : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c1131c1ade963048266a0e426e9357232aaddd5